# derivatives by a and b, using using algorithmic differentiation

Tags: python, numpy, jax

I've been tasked to find the derivatives by a and b, using jax, for this
[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSpk1.png)

now, the reason I'm here is because I don't know enough Python, and this for the course in question, we haven't been thought python either.

the assignment is:

```
return a tuple (dfa, dfb) such that dfa is the partial derivatives of f by a,
           and dfb is the partial derivative of f by b
```

now, I was able to do it the normal way:

```
def function(a, b):
   dfa = sym.diff((2/b)*sym.cos(a)*sym.exp(-a*a/b*b), a)
   dfb = sym.diff((2/b)*sym.cos(a)*sym.exp(-a*a/b*b), a)
   return (dfa, dfb)
```

but im not familiar with  algorithmic differentiation, using the example we were given, i've tried this:

```
def foo():

   x = (2/b)*sym.cos(a)
   y = sym.exp(-sym.Pow(a/b,2))
   return (x*y)

def f_partial_derviatives_algo():
   return jax.grad(foo)
```

but I'm getting this error:

> cannot unpack non-iterable function object

If anyone can help with understanding how i can do something like that, It would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using `sympy`?  Why the `numpy` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX and sympy are not compatible. You should either use one or the other, and not try to combine the two.

If you want to compute the partial derivatives of this function at some value using JAX, you can write something like this:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad

def f(a, b):
  return (2 / b) * jnp.cos(a) * jnp.exp(- a ** 2 / b ** 2)

df_da = grad(f, argnums=0)
df_db = grad(f, argnums=1)

print(df_da(1.0, 1.0), df_db(1.0, 1.0))
# -1.4141841 0.3975322
```